# How do I make Ubuntu sleep after my TV is switched off?

Tags: ubuntu, sleep, tv

I would like my HTPC box (Ubuntu) to automatically sleep after my TV is either switched off, or another HDMI source is selected (TiVo box).  Also, I would like my HTPC box to wake up again if the TV is switched back on and the correct HDMI source is selected.

Is that possible?

P.S.

I do not want the HTPC box to sleep if the TV is on and the correct HDMI source is selected, regardless of idle time.